# How to check if value exists in another properties json schema

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

I need to validate if the value is existed in another properties in the json file, not the schema file. I wonder if that even possible.

I already search for some keyword like "lookup" or "reference" but the result are reference to the schema file, not the json data.

Here are the schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "title": "List of people cars",
  "properties": {
    "car":{
      "type":"array",
      "items": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type":"string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "people": {
      "type":"array",
      "items":{
        "properties": {
          "fullname":{
            "type":"string"
          },
          "cars":{
            "type":"string"
            // somehow validate if the car exist in car properties
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the json data

```
{
  "$schema": "./schema.json",
  "car": [
    {
      "name": "Lamborghini"
    }
  ],
  "people": [
    {
      "fullname": "Ucok",
      "cars": "Lamborghini" //check if the car name exist in the car properties
    }
  ]
}
```

I expect the cars properties value from people object is autocompleting from the list of car listed above

Answer (score 0):

in order to check if a value exists with javascript you can use find / findIndex

```
let test = {
  "$schema": "./schema.json",
  "car": [
    {
      "name": "Lamborghini"
    }
  ],
  "people": [
    {
      "fullname": "Ucok",
      "cars": "Lamborghini" //check if the car name exist in the car properties
    }
  ]
};

test.car.find((item) => item.name === 'Lamborghini'); // will return {name: 'Lamborghini'}
test.car.find((item) => item.name === 'Ferrari'); // will return undefined

test.car.findIndex((item) => item.name === 'Lamborghini'); // will return 0
test.car.findIndex((item) => item.name === 'Ferrari'); // will return -1
```

if the return value is undefined or -1 then the value doesn't exists

Comment: i appreciate the answer. but i ask about json, not javascript.

Comment: just assumed since you tagged javascript